# ckeditor5 - hiding 3 dot menu when you click a button on the small screen

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I found an issue at ckeditor5, I cant find any solution for it. Movie:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fHeZ3pL9K-xc3JRq0G8C9zU8bOzXmE8X/view?usp=sharing

**DESCRIPTION**
In general after resize browser to imitate smaller screen, the 3 dots menu appears , and after click it, sometimes it just hide just after I clicked it.

**ASSUMPTION**
I notice that the first element in the dropdown shown has focus on itself (blue border). Maybe this is a hint? but I don't know how to manipulate it from the outside.

**QUESTION:**
How to fix / any hint a / is ckeditor allow us to add some custom js or css?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "4.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-translations": "32.1.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "32.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "35.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "35.4.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^29.0.4",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-alignment": "^29.0.7",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-autosave": "^32.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-clipboard": "^29.0.5",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-cloud-services": "^29.0.4",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-code-block": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-collaboration-core": "^27.1.2",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-core": "^33.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^27.1.2",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-engine": "^32.0.11",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-enter": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-export-pdf": "^31.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-export-word": "^27.0.4",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-font": "^33.0.1",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-heading": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-highlight": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-image": "^33.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-indent": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-language": "^32.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-link": "^32.0.4",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-media-embed": "^29.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-mention": "^31.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-minimap": "^33.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-pagination": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-paragraph": "^27.0.5",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-real-time-collaboration": "^32.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-restricted-editing": "^32.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-table": "^33.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-track-changes": "^32.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-typing": "^32.0.1",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-ui": "^32.0.2",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-undo": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-upload": "^27.0.7",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-utils": "^28.0.14",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-widget": "^33.0.1",
    "@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-word-count": "^29.0.2",
```

Comment: I found that the tooltip in some situations does not appear in the browser window because it does not fit in the window

when we change its direction or place the ckeditor higher, everything is ok